# RODBC import to keep "NA"

Tags: r

When I import country data using RODBC I often use ISO2 codes. The unfortunate part is Namibia with ISO2 "NA" always gets set to missing. There are various ways around this of course, but I wonder if anyone has found a way to just import correctly. I've tried

```
df <- sqlFetch(ch,"data_from_database", na.strings="")
df <- sqlFetch(ch,"data_from_database", as.is)
```

to no avail. Any tips?

Comment: First one should work. What are your versions of R, RODBC and what database you use?

Comment: as.is=T doesn't seem to work either. I'm using R version 2.10.1 and RODBC 1.3-1. My database is on SQLserver, but I have the same problem importing from Excel via RODBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HA! Well as.is=T doesn't work, na.string="" doesn't work, but with their powers combined...

```
> ch <- odbcConnectExcel("m.xls")
> s <- sqlFetch(ch, "m", as.is=T)
> close(ch)
> s 
  iso2 value
1   GB    87
2 <NA>   456
3   IN   423
> ch <- odbcConnectExcel("m.xls")
> r <- sqlFetch(ch, "m", na.string="")
> close(ch)
> r 
  iso2 value
1   GB    87
2 <NA>   456
3   IN   423
> ch <- odbcConnectExcel("m.xls")
> n <- sqlFetch(ch, "m", as.is=T, na.string="")
> close(ch)
> n 
  iso2 value
1   GB    87
2   NA   456
3   IN   423
```

Comment: It's look like a "bug" in `sqlGetResults`. I checked source and it seems that `na.string` is not pass to `type.convert` used in `sqlGetResults`.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the database loaders eventually call `read.table()`.  So as a first step, let's address that.

With a data file `tom.csv` as

```
country,value
GB,55
NA,77
CH,23
```

I get

```
R> read.csv("/tmp/tom.csv")
  country value
1      GB    55
2    <NA>    77
3      CH    23
R> read.csv("/tmp/tom.csv", na.string="#")
  country value
1      GB    55
2      NA    77
3      CH    23
R>
```

so simple setting `na.string` to a different value was sufficient.

Try that along with `sqlQuery()` which is more directly useful than `sqlFetch()`.

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. Your solution works great for read.csv, but the same thing doesn't work with sqlFetch or sqlQuery. Perhaps it's some kind of bug? In the meantime I'll just keep using my workaround function.